# What is an optimal way to design a product database schema when products can vary greatly?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, filemaker

I am trying to design a product database using FileMaker 14. Our products are mainly:

- Adapters: HDMI to DisplayPort; USB to VGA; USB to Ethernet; SD/micro SD card/Compact Flash readers etc...
- Docking Stations: USB-C to DisplayPort/HDMI/USB-A 2.0/USB-A 3.0/USB-C 3.0/USB-C 2.0/AUX-in/AUX-out, etc...
- USB Hubs: 2/4/6/8/10-port USB hubs, can be powered by bus or power adapter, with or without Ethernet, etc...
- Possibly other types of product in the future

I want the database to be able to, among other things, output a spec sheet, which will include:

- Model Number
- Product Name
- Image (one if printed, multiple if shown on laptop or tablet)
- Upstream interface (All kinds of video, data, audio)
- Downstream interfaces (All kinds of video, data, audio)
- Power source (Bus or power adapter, different types of power adapters)
- Dimensions
- Weight
- Operating environments
- Supported operating systems

I've tried to normalize these as best as I can, but I'm confused with how the **interfaces** should be implemented. Options I think I have:

1. Lump them together in one table

   ```
   ProductUpstreamInterfaces:
   ProductID (primary foreign key)
   USB-A2
   USB-A3
   USB-B
   USB-C2
   USB-C3
   Thunderbolt1
   Thunderbolt2
   Thunderbolt3
   AUX-in
   AUX-out
   HDMI
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   and

   ```
   ProductDownstreamInterfaces:
   ProductID (primary foreign key)
   USB-A2
   USB-A3
   USB-B
   USB-C2
   USB-C3
   Thunderbolt1
   Thunderbolt2
   Thunderbolt3
   AUX-in
   AUX-out
   HDMI
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   Where the values for each field would be the quantities.
2. Break them apart

   ```
   ProductInterfaces:
   ProductID (primary foreign key)
   InterfaceID (foreign key)
   Quantity
   Direction_1Up2Down (1 for up; 2 for down)
   ```

   and

   ```
   Interfaces:
   InterfaceID (primary key)
   Interface (eg. HDMI/DisplayPort/USB-C2/USB-C3/AUX-in/AUX-out, etc...)
   ```

Option 1 seems really messy.

Option 2 seems better, but I'm not sure if I'm going to run into any problems down the road... Which of the two is better? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With very few exceptions, anytime you have many of Y (interfaces) related to one X (product), you should put them in separate tables. When the join itself has attributes (such as Quantity in your example), there can be no exceptions.

OTOH, I don't see why you would need the third table ("Interfaces"). Does it have any other fields besides those shown? If not, a custom value list should be quite sufficient.

---

### Caveat

Make sure you don't overthink this. Sometimes a list of interfaces is just text in a field. It all depends on what your solution intends to accomplish. A many-to-many relationship, supported by a join table, is useful when you need to track which interfaces are in use in which products, be able to quickly create/modify the interfaces for a product, perhaps produce some statistics (e.g. "*80% of products in category X feature interface Y*"), etc. Otherwise it's just waste of resources.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying option two is the way to go, but with just the ProductInterfaces table? The Interfaces table is there because somehow I thought it is best practice to put repetitive fields in a separate table with a primary key as a way to reduce redundancy; for example, using an auto-generated numeric value as InterfaceID rather than using HDMI over and over again.<br />
Also, I have to admit I don't quite grasp how custom value lists in FileMaker work...

Comment: "*so you're saying option two is the way to go, but with just the ProductInterfaces table?*" Yes. --  "*I thought it is best practice to put repetitive fields in a separate table with a primary key as a way to reduce redundancy*" Generally, that's true. But `HDMI` is just as unique and permanent as `123`, and repeating `HDMI` is no more redundant than repeating `123`.

Comment: "Generally, that's true." My apologies, I'm getting a little confused... Might you be able to point me a link where this is explained in more detail? I'm not quite clear in which circumstances this should be done. If aside from HDMI, USB-A, etc, I also had a field for version numbers (USB 3.0, 3.1 Gen 1, HDMI 2.0, etc), would a separate table be preferable?

Comment: If you had an additional field, then a table would become inevitable. Also if the type would not be unique in this table (as shown in your example), then a meaningless ID would also be required.